Authenticating Copilot with Directline Api not working with OAUTH
I have implemented oAuth in Copilot authentication and after that the bot signin is not properly working .
I am using custom copilot canvas and directline api for the requirements.
Here's my code snippet which stopped working :
if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/INCOMING_ACTIVITY') {
    debugger
    const activity = action.payload.activity;
    let resourceUri;
    if (activity.from && activity.from.role === 'bot' &&
        (resourceUri = getOAuthCardResourceUri(activity))) {
        exchangeTokenAsync(resourceUri).then(function (token) {
            if (token) {
                directLine.postActivity({
                    type: 'invoke',
                    name: 'signin/tokenExchange',
                    value: {
                        id: activity.conversation.id,
                        connectionName: activity.attachments[0].content.connectionName,
                        token
                    },
                    "from": {
                        id: userId,
                        name: clientApplication.account.name,
                        role: "user"
                    }
                }).subscribe(
                    id => {
                        if (id === 'retry') {
                            return next(action);
                        }
                    },
                    error => {
                        return next(action);
                    }
                );
                return;
            }

Any suggestions or solutions to this will be helpful
